# Ruby parse DateTime with variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm trying to parse a specific hour of a specific date. When I put the date directly as an argument, it works fine, but when I create a variable and put it in the argument it returns the current date.

Why is that?

NOTE: the variable time is `9pm` and I need to parse `9pm` of `12 March 2016`.

```
datetime = DateTime.new(2016,3,12,9)
=> Sat, 12 Mar 2016 09:00:00 +0000

DateTime.parse("sat 12 march 2016 9pm")
=> Sat, 12 Mar 2016 21:00:00 +0000

DateTime.parse("datetime 9pm")
=> Mon, 14 Mar 2016 21:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Where is hour variable?

Comment: I meant variable time!

Comment: *"the variable hour is 9am 12 March"* - that looks like an hour, a day and a month. What's the variable part and what's the fixed part?

Comment: BTW, you should probably use `Time` (or Rails' `TimeWithZone`) instead of `DateTime`

Comment: Very good point! thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your third call, you use the literal string "datetime" rather than the value of your `datetime` variable. You can use string interpolation to use the variable's value:

```
DateTime.parse("#{datetime} 9pm")
```

In this case, the "9pm" is ignored since it doesn't make sense added to the end of an existing date but this is why the initial attempt wasn't working. Interpolation is generally a solution for using a variable's value rather than its name.

If your goal is to change the time of an existing date, use the [change method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-change):

```
datetime.change(hour:21)
```

Comment: OK. It parses the correct date now, but not 9pm! It still parses the `datetime` hour which is 9am.

Comment: Ah, that's right. You really don't need parse in this case. Can you use something like `datetime.change(hour:17)` instead?

Comment: Right!!! Funny I used the change method just 10 lines below this code but didn't think of it :D Would you edit your answer so that I accept it?

Comment: @fardin you may want to edit your question to clarify that you are using Rails.

Comment: @HélèneMartin you may want to edit your answer, too. `DateTime.parse("#{datetime} 9pm")` obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this

```
date = Date.new(2016,3,12)

DateTime.parse("#{date} 9pm")
## Output
Sat, 12 Mar 2016 21:00:00 +0000
```

**OR**

```
datetime = DateTime.new(2016,3,12,9)

DateTime.parse((datetime + 12.hours).to_s)
## Output
Sat, 12 Mar 2016 21:00:00 +0000
```

**OR**

```
DateTime.parse((datetime + 12.hours).to_s).strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M %p")
## Output
Sat, 12 Mar 2016 09:00 PM
```